# Android Studio Gradle Unit Tests Not Working

Tags: java, android, gradle, build

I am unfamiliar with Gradle, particularly as it relates to Android Studio . I have written a unit test

Here it the path: /app/src/test/java/ui/NumberAdderTest.java

I can can right click on the file from my project view and run it and get it to fail and pass correctly. However, what I want is the failure of the test to prevent the build from succeeding, and not let the app deploy.

Here is my build.graddle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "code.cse.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testApplicationId = 'src/test/java'
}
buildTypes {
   release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), ...
   }
}
}
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
   testCompile 'junit: junit:4.12'
   testComple 'org.mockito.mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare a sourceset for your test
2. Create a gradle task for this test
3. Put Gradle `dependsOn` in your `build.gradle`.

   ```
   sourceSets {
       myTest {
           java {
               srcDir file('src/test/java')
           }
           resources.srcDir file('src/test/resources')
       }
   }

   task myTest(type: Test) {
       testClassesDir = sourceSets.myTest.output.classesDir
       classpath = sourceSets.myTest.runtimeClasspath
   }

   check.dependsOn myTest
   ```